# Get an array of all UITextFields in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a static TableView that I am using as a form for user input.  I am currently adding targets to each TextField so that I can add `textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField)` for `UIControl.Event.editingChanged`

I would like to add all the TextFields to an array so that I can loop through and do this for all the TextFields without having to manual do it for each one.

I have tried the following, but it does not work:

```
var textFields = [UITextField]()
for view in self.view.subviews {
    if let textField = view as? UITextField {
        textFields.append(textField)
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You should add target to your `UITextField`s inside `tableView(_:, cellForRowAt:) -> UITableViewCell` function

Comment: Your code doesn't work because you are doing a shallow iteration of the subviews. The text fields are going to be much deeper within the view hierarchy.

Comment: Do you have the cells in storyboard?

Comment: @RajeshKumarR Yes, the cells were added using storyboard

Comment: @K.Wu static table view controller doesn't have `cellForRow` method

Answer (score 1):

Create a `IBOutlet` collection connection in the UITableViewController and connect all text fields with the connection. Then you can use this IBOutlet collection as an array of `UITextField`

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet var textFields: [UITextField]!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        textFields.forEach {
            $0.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
        }
    }
    @objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Plus 1 for the targets, what's the outlet connection for though?

Comment: Outlet connection is the array of textfields. It can be used to validate all text fields